# How to count and show duplicate in php string?

Tags: php, string, count, duplicates, show

To create a ranking, I would like to count and then show duplicate entries in a string

```
<?php

$orgasql = "SELECT organisateur FROM events ";                                  
$orgareq = $bdd->prepare($orgasql);                                     
$orgareq->execute();                                        
while($eventrow = $orgareq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                                      
$eventorgaas[] = $eventrow['organisateur'];                                     
}                                       
$eventimploded = implode(',',$eventorgaas);                                     
$eventimploded = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $eventimploded)));                                       
echo $eventimploded
?>
```

The current code returns this result :

```
Holyblood,Nessy,Pokégaia,Sorrow,JOHN
```

I would like the result to be this :

```
Holyblood - 2 ,Nessy - 1,Pokégaia - 1,Sorrow -1,JOHN -1
```

(There are two "Holyblood" occurrences in my database, array_unique delete duplica)

Comment: read count + group by

Comment: why not just `GROUP BY`? What is the real thing you actually try to achieve - the entire story?

Comment: Try this: "SELECT organisateur, count(*) count FROM events GROUP BY organisateur";

Comment: Indeed, I will use GROUP BY.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group by them by `organisateur` and count their occurences:

```
<?php
$orgasql = "SELECT organisateur, COUNT(*) as count FROM events GROUP BY organisateur";                                  
$orgareq = $bdd->prepare($orgasql);                                     
$orgareq->execute();                                        
while($eventrow = $orgareq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                                      
    $eventorgaas[] = $eventrow['organisateur'] . '-' . $eventrow['count'] ;                                     
}                                       
$eventimploded = implode(',',$eventorgaas);                                      
echo $eventimploded
?>
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you !

Comment: Welcome..... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with sql

```
select organisateur, count(*) my_count
from events
group by  organisateur
```

or

```
select concat(organisateur, ' - ' ,  count(*))  my_result
from events
group by organisateur
```